# How to change spines linewidth in 3D plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When you have a 2D plot in matplolib you can change the line width of spines (the containing box) as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,2,3])
spines = ax.spines
[i.set_linewidth(5) for i in spines.values()]
```

Figure with thick spines:
[image: notice super thick box lines]

However this same methodology does not work for 3D plots.
How could I change the axes line thickness for a 3D plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the following code. I adapted the idea of accessing the axes in 3D from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19576145/4932316) answer. If you want to change the thickness of all the grid lines as well, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41924889/4932316) answer by [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for axis in [ax.w_xaxis, ax.w_yaxis, ax.w_zaxis]:
    axis.line.set_linewidth(5)
```

[image]